# SQL, Too many values, Result consolidation

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, profiling, ora-00913

I have a problem with an SQL query, in fact when i try to execute this i have this response :
what i want to do is to calculate the sum and the count

Can you help me please ? thank you a lot

ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:
*Action:
Erreur à la ligne 2, colonne 5

---

```
select distinct 
(select sum(che1.mon), count(che1.typ)
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1 
where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.pie=che1.pie and che.typ in ('T','C')),

(select sum(che1.mon) 
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1 
where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.typ = che1.typ and che.typ ='F'),

che.ncp, 
m.cpro, m.age,  m.ribdec,  m.dev,
p.lib, cli.cli, cli.pre, cli.nom, 
adcli.adr1, adcli.adr2, adcli.adr3, adcli.cpos, adcli.ville
from 
awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che, awbeprod_fr.bkcom m, 
awbeprod_fr.bkprod p, awbeprod_fr.bkcli cli, 
awbeprod_fr.bkadcli adcli
where che.ncp = m.ncp 
and che.cli = m.cli and m.cli = cli.cli
and cli.cli = adcli.cli and m.cpro = p.cpro
and che.ncp = '11000003415'
order by che.ncp
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Usage of ANSI JOIN would make your request clearer, and usage of GROUP BY should help you to do "all in one".

```
SELECT 
SUM (CASE WHEN che.typ in ('T', 'C') THEN che.mon ELSE 0 END) sumMonTC,
SUM (CASE WHEN che.typ in ('T', 'C') THEN 1       ELSE 0 END) cntMonTC,
SUM (CASE WHEN che.typ ='F'          THEN che.mon ELSE 0 END) sumMonF,
che.ncp, 
m.cpro, m.age,  m.ribdec,  m.dev,
p.lib, cli.cli, cli.pre, cli.nom, 
adcli.adr1, adcli.adr2, adcli.adr3, adcli.cpos, adcli.ville

FROM awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che
    INNER JOIN awbeprod_fr.bkcom m ON che.ncp = m.ncp AND che.cli = m.cli
    INNER JOIN awbeprod_fr.bkprod p ON m.cpro = p.cpro
    INNER JOIN awbeprod_fr.bkcli cli ON m.cli = cli.cli
    INNER JOIN awbeprod_fr.bkadcli adcli on cli.cli = adcli.cli
WHERE che.ncp = '11000003415'
GROUP BY che.ncp, 
m.cpro, m.age,  m.ribdec,  m.dev,
p.lib, cli.cli, cli.pre, cli.nom, 
adcli.adr1, adcli.adr2, adcli.adr3, adcli.cpos, adcli.ville
ORDER BY che.ncp
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your query isn't correct because it doesn't calculate the right sum amount because there's a missing condition which is : where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.pie=che1.pie and che.typ in ('T','C')), in fact i used subqueries to ensure i calculate the sum for all data that have the sape che.ncp and che.pie and a typ in ('T','C') or your query takes in account only the che.typ conditioin, so the sum isn't correct. how can we do in that case ?

Comment: @user2008204 You have to use "where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.pie = che1.pie" part because you make a join on the same table. In my query, I don't use the table twice (no che1), so that comparison isn't needed. Which doesn't mean my query gives the perfect result, there's maybe another problem, but not the one you point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i need to do that comparaison whether my sum and count calculation won't be correct. indeed i need to calculate the sum for all data that have the same che.ncp, this is why i used the table twice. otherwise is there any other method to not use the table twice and have a correct result ? thank you in advance

Comment: @user2008204 just same che.ncp, or same che.ncp AND same che.pie

Comment: @user2008204 do `select sum(che.mon), count(che.typ)
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1
where che.ncp = '11000003415' AND  che.typ  IN ('T','C') GROUP BY che.ncp, che.pie` return many lines ? and `select sum(che.mon), count(che.typ)
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1
where che.ncp = '11000003415' AND  che.typ  IN ('T','C') GROUP BY che.ncp` ?

Comment: both of them don't work because a select statment can't return a count and a sum

Comment: @user2008204 Not in your query, just these 2 queries alone. A select statement can perfectly return a sum and a count.

Answer (score 0):

If you use subquery you have to return one value not two or more. So just divide your first subquery to two:

```
select distinct 
(select sum(che1.mon)
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1 
where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.pie=che1.pie and che.typ in ('T','C')),

(select count(che1.typ)
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1 
where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.pie=che1.pie and che.typ in ('T','C')),

(select sum(che1.mon) 
from awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che1 
where che.ncp = che1.ncp and che.typ = che1.typ and che.typ ='F'),

che.ncp, 
m.cpro, m.age,  m.ribdec,  m.dev,
p.lib, cli.cli, cli.pre, cli.nom, 
adcli.adr1, adcli.adr2, adcli.adr3, adcli.cpos, adcli.ville
from 
awbeprod_fr.CHE_BKFRACOMC che, awbeprod_fr.bkcom m, 
awbeprod_fr.bkprod p, awbeprod_fr.bkcli cli, 
awbeprod_fr.bkadcli adcli
where che.ncp = m.ncp 
and che.cli = m.cli and m.cli = cli.cli
and cli.cli = adcli.cli and m.cpro = p.cpro
and che.ncp = '11000003415'
order by che.ncp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is when i use subquery is that instead of returning me 1 result (line) it returns me 7 lines. and i have a huge amount of data in my database, so it's going to return me over 700 000 results ...

Comment: @user2008204  Oracle show you error at line 2 so it is your subquery with SUM and COUNT. You can't return both from subquery. Try a SQL statement from my answer. Also if you use SUM or COUNT your subquery can't return more than one value (if you don't use GROUP BY).